# Data not retrieved from Google Drive with the service account (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-drive-api

Hi I created the google service account with the email A@gmail.com.
I downloaded secret json file and put into the working directory.
Then initialize and authorize api with this type of commands.

```
scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)
```

It works at this stage with the out of

> > ## https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token>, @client_id=nil, @client_secret=nil, @code=nil, @expires_at=nil, @expires_in=nil, @issued_at=nil, @issuer="brbr@appspot.gserviceaccount.com", @password=nil, @principal=nil, @redirect_uri=nil, @scope=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"], @state=nil, @username=nil, @expiry=60, @audience="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token", @signing_key=#, @extension_parameters={}, @additional_parameters={}>

Then, I ran the below command as Google api document explains.

```
response = service.list_files(page_size: 10,
                              fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)')
puts 'Files:'
puts 'No files found' if response.files.empty?
response.files.each do |file|
  puts "#{file.name} (#{file.id})"
end
```

The only file that is retrieved is "Getting Started" file even if I recalled with page_size 10.

Inside of google drive whose email account is A@gmail.com, I created a couple of files ( google document, google spread sheet , etc) but none of them are retrieved with the command above.

Is that because of the service account?

For instance, my service account email(client_email) is brbrbrbr...@appspot.gserviceaccount.com, which is apparently different from A@gmail.com.

Please give me any idea on this issue!

Best

Comment: Did you [Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/delegation)?

Comment: Hi @noogui!, I tried to delegate the domain wide access to this service account in the admin console page. As it explains, I put the client id of my service account under the Client Name. My service account client id is a number(21digits).  And I also inserted the scope. But the error message appears : This client name has not been registered with Google yet. 
Would you tell me what might be the reason for this? (:

Comment: Hi @noogui! I just granted "g suit domain wide access authority to this account under my A@gmail.com". However, still my files that are stored inside the google drive of A@gmail.com don't get retrieved from the server. Would you give me any hint for this? (: